# Jersey request filter delegate to different server

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I have a cluster with 3 web services (all are the same) and a load balancer.

I would like to implement a `ContainerRequestFilter` which intercepts a request and checks for a specific header of a web service id.
Given the header exists, I need to delegate the request (as is, with headers, params etc.) to the specific web service and return it's response.

Is this possible by implementing only `ContainerRequestFilter` or do I need something else or something in addition?
I'm using Jersey 1.9 if that matters.

Thanks.

Comment: Would you not be better doing that in the load balancer? You can usually do some kind of content-based routing in load balancers and what you're proposing sounds like it could be confusing from an operational perspective - when you're tracing a request you'll find yourself bouncing around between 2 nodes in your cluster and each node still needs to do the header checking even after it's been checked once.

Comment: I'm afraid I need an applicative solution as the load balancer is not controlled by me.
I don't understand why you say it will be confusing, the entire operation should be transparent to the user (and to the admin).

Comment: If anything goes wrong and you're investigating what happened to a request you'll have to track it through 2 nodes in your network rather than 1. It definitely has potential to be confusing. Also, the load balancer's effectiveness in managing traffic is going to be reduced, and the reason for that may not be well understood if your load-balancer owner doesn't understand what you're doing. It just seems like you're jumping through hoops to add complexity.